# Bootstrap keep accordion in the same height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I try to keep a Bootstrap accordion in the same height when the user click on another collapse pannel. The pannels should onclick wrap the space to get the accordion full hight and make the pannel content scrollable if the content getting too big. Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhcpuequ/3/)!

```
var header = $('.panel-heading');
var test = $(window).height() - (header.length*$('.panel-heading').height());
$('.panel-body').height(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your CSS, HTML and JS.. I don't know how to do this with JQuery, so i've used normal javascript:

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-heading');
var headingheights = header.length * (header[0].offsetHeight + 18); 
var test = $(window).height() - headingheights;
$('.panel-body').height(test);
```

Note:
All Panelbodys must have the same padding, so ive wrapped your list in a own div with a margin of -15px (same effect as your solution)

I've added some comments inside the fiddle for you to explain... ;)

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hhcpuequ/11/

I hope this is what you are searching for ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot... that is exactly what what I'm looking for.